# Does there exist a weak solution in $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ to the following equation: $-\Delta u+bu=f$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded open subset in $\mathbb{R^3}$, $f$ and $b$ be in $L^2(\Omega)$ such that $b$ is non-negative on $\Omega$. Does there exist a weak solution in $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ to the following equation: $-\Delta u+bu=f$?

Help me some hints to start. Furthermore, tell me some textbook about PDEs which contains many problems like this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: is the bilinear form
$$
a(u,v)=\int_\Omega(\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+b\,u\,v),\quad u,v\in W_0^{1,1}(\Omega),
$$
coercive?

There are excelent books by [L.C. Evans](http://books.google.es/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations.html?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&redir_esc=y) and [H. Brèzis](http://books.google.es/books/about/Functional_Analysis_Sobolev_Spaces_and_P.html?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Did you $u,v\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Thanks, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 If the answer has been useful to you and you think it completely answers your question, please accept it. Otherwise it will be considered unanswered.

Comment: I need more details. Did you imply $a(u,v)$ is a weak solution of that equation?

Comment: $u\in W_0^{1,2}$ is a weak solution if $a(u,v)=\int_\Omega f\,v$ for all $v\in W_0^{1,2}$. If $a$ is coercive, use the [Lax-Milgram theorem](http://www.math.lmu.de/~michel/lax-milgram).